# git add -p (interactive patch) and edit mode gives a "corrupt patch at line XX" error

Tags: git, edit, git-patch

I'm addind my change to a commit with `git add -p`, now I'd like to use the manual hunk edit mode.

I simply have this hunk:

```
# Manual hunk edit mode -- see bottom for a quick guide
@@ -46,6 +46,7 @@ function signIn(email, password) {
             }
         })
         .catch((error) => {
+            console.log(error);
             ToastAndroid.show(translations.translations.error_occurred, ToastAndroid.SHORT);
             that.setState({isLoading: false});
         });
# ---
# To remove '-' lines, make them ' ' lines (context).
# To remove '+' lines, delete them.
# Lines starting with # will be removed.
```

If I delete completely the line added (with `console.log`) then save and quit the editor, I get this error:

```
error: corrupt patch at line 12
```

I have totally no idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The only change the patch hunk makes is to add that one line. If you take it out, the patch becomes a directive to change the file by making no change to the file, which is not sensible. The error message here is kind of silly but the action you need is simply "skip this one".

Comment: Ok thanks, so if there was an other line added that I didn't touch, I wouldn't have any error? And I don't want to skip this one but I want to cancel the change. Do I have to skip the change and checkout after? (I hope that here is a faster way to achieve this.)

Comment: Yes, if there were still some other change the modified patch should apply. Note that what you are doing is, in fact, editing the copy of the file that is in the *index*. There are three copies of each file at all times. The two obvious ones are the committed version in the current commit—you cannot change this one!—and the easy-to-see-and-edit one in your *work-tree*. You can edit that one in your favorite editor at any time. But there is a *third* copy, stored in what Git calls the *index* or the *staging-area* or the *cache* (three names for the same thing). [continued]

Comment: The index copy starts out matching the committed file. If you run `git add <filename>`, Git simply copies the *work-tree* version into the index, so now the index copy matches the work-tree version. These are the two most common situations: *matches HEAD* or *matches work-tree*. (If HEAD and work-tree copies match, the index copy can and usually does match both.) What `git add -p` is *for* is to take whatever's *different* between work-tree copy and index copy, and add *some* of that difference to the index copy. This leaves the work-tree version alone! It only patches the index copy.

Comment: Thanks for all these explications, you can post the first response in order to me to accept it.

Comment: OK. BTW I goofed up the description of `git reset -p`, so I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[note: comments turned into answer - the top section is all you need, the rest is just explication]

The only change the patch hunk makes is to add that one line.  If you take out the added line, the patch becomes a directive to change the file by making no change to the file, which is not very sensible.  The error message here is kind of silly, but the action you need is simply "skip this one".

#### Lots of details, read only if interesting

Note that there are, at all times while you're working on your next commit to make, three of what I call *active copies* of each file.  Well, more precisely, there are *up to* three such copies.  The first one is whatever you committed previously, or had inside the commit that you got when you ran `git checkout`.  This copy, being stored inside a commit, is fundamentally read-only: you *cannot* change it, as it's part of that particular commit.  But you can *access* it whenever you like.  For instance, given a `README.txt` file you can run:

```
git show HEAD:README.txt
```

to view it.  Internally, this file is stored in a special Git-only format (zlib-deflated and perhaps even further compressed)—non-Git programs in general cannot read this copy of the file.

There's also a copy of that same file in your *work-tree*, where you can work on it.  This copy is stored in its ordinary computer format, so that you can read it.  Your editor—atom or emacs or sublime or vim or whatever it is you use—can read and write the file.  Your compiler, if you compile programs, can read and write it, and so on.  You need not do anything special with the file, as it's just like any other file.  Oddly, *Git* almost doesn't care about this copy of `README.txt`—Git has to be kind of hands-off, since *anything* can change it!

But there's a *third* copy of `README.txt` too, and that's the one that is in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  (Which name Git uses depends on which Git documentation you're looking at.)  This third copy, which you can see with `git show :README.txt`, is in the special Git-only format, but unlike the copy in a *commit*, you *can* overwrite this one.  The usual *way* that you overwrite this one is with `git add`, which simply *copies the work-tree file into the index*.

Hence, the index `:README.txt` *starts out* matching the `HEAD:README.txt` file.  If you change the work-tree copy, the HEAD and index versions still match.  If you then `git add README.txt`, that overwrites the index copy from the work-tree copy, and now `HEAD:README.txt` and `README.txt` no longer match, but `:README.txt` *does* match `README.txt`.

This is where `git add -p` comes in: if the *index* copy and the *work-tree* copy of some file are different, you can have Git come up with a patch—a set of hunks, each of which says to add and/or remove some line or lines—that, if applied, would *change* the index version to match the work-tree version.  If Git were to follow all the instructions in the patch, that would change the index copy of the file to match the work-tree copy, just like `git add` would do.

But now Git has *you* go through that patch, one patch-hunk at a time, and:

- tell Git to apply it as is; or
- tell Git to skip it entirely; or even
- fiddle with the change instructions so as to *partially* apply the patch.

When you choose to apply a particular patch-hunk (perhaps after editing it), Git extracts the index version of the file, applies that set of instructions, and goes on to look at the next one.  If you skip it, Git just goes on to the next one.

Note that there is a companion to `git add -p`: running `git reset -p README.txt` tells Git that it should compare `HEAD:README.txt` and `:README.txt` (HEAD and index versions), and prepare a patch that would, if followed to the letter, change the index copy so that it matches the `HEAD` copy again.  Then Git goes through the same process as for `git add -p`.

---

Last, let's take a quick look at `git status`.  This does a lot of useful things, but the one where it tells you about *changes staged for commit* and *changes not staged for commit* consists of running, in essence, two `git diff` commands.  The first one is:

- What's different in `HEAD` vs the index?

For every file that is exactly the same here, Git is just silent about that.  But if `HEAD:README.txt` and `:README.txt` are different, Git tells you that there is something *staged for commit* in `README.txt`.

Having listed all of those files, Git runs a second diff, this time to find out:

- What's different in the index vs the work-tree?

Here, any file that's *different*, Git tells you that there is something *not staged for commit*.  That's because you *could* run `git add` on that file, to copy it into the index.

If you were to run `git commit` right now, Git would make the *new* commit from *whatever is in the index right now*, so `HEAD`-vs-index tells you: *these files **would** be different, in this new commit, from what's in the **current** commit.*  Meanwhile index-vs-work-tree tells you: *these files **could** be different, but won't be unless you `git add` them.*

This second diff is also the step that discovers any *untracked* files.  An untracked file is, quite simply, a file that's in the work-tree, but not in the index.  If such a file is *ignored*, Git shuts up about it.  If the untracked file is *not* ignored, Git tells you that it is untracked.  Note that a file that *is* in the index is by definition tracked, so Git never even checks for an ignore directive.

This fact—about new / untracked files—is why there are *up to* three copies of each file.  If you create a new file, it's not in the `HEAD` commit at all.  It's also untracked until you `git add` the file to copy it into the index.  So you start out with one copy, in the work-tree only; then you have two, in the index and work-tree.  Then you make a *new* commit, which *becomes* the current (`HEAD`) commit, and only then are there three copies of that new file.